# #VALUE! error in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

```
=IF(ISBLANK(S3);"";CONCATENATE(" UPDATE kkr_urunkredi ku
   SET ";IF(ISBLANK($A3);"";CONCATENATE(" ku.yatirimsuresi =''";$A3;"''"));"
       ku.kredikonu_kd  =''";$B3;"'',
       ku.kademeli_drm  ='";IF(S$2 <> $AJ2;H;E);"'
 WHERE ku.kkr_urun_kd =";S3;""))
```

There is a mistake here with the conditional `IF(S$2 <> $AJ2;H;E)`. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently changing `IF(S$2 <> $AJ2;H;E)` to `IF(S$2 <> $AJ2;"H";"E")` fixed the issue.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution @blgnklc. It helps the community

Comment: @emb1995: An answer posted by the question author cannot be accepted until 48 hours after the question was asked.